# Solve and find the flaw in this integral equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

The following integral equation often appears in the books and it has once been
asked in the prestigious examination called IIT JEE (M) dated 10-04-2016. The question is:
$\forall x \in R-\{0\}$, if $y(x)$ is  differentiable function such that
$$ x\int_{1}^{x}~ y(t)~dt =(x+1) \int_{1}^{x} t ~y(t)~dt.$$
Find $y(x)$. Some four interesting expression of $y(x)$ were given as alternatives in this MCQ type question.

Solving this you may find a serious flaw in this question.

I would like to thank Ninad Sutrave for expressing a doubt about this question.

Comment: The left integral starts at 0, the right integral starts at 1.

Comment: Thanks Marty for pointing out this typo by me. The question stands correct now..

Comment: The function $y(x) = 0$ is differentiable and satisfies the equation.

Comment: Yes Eyeballfrog, you are right. The text books and that exam did not like this answer! But, still a good educational  commentary is required. We should not let go this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw in the question is that $y(x) = 0$ obviously satisfies the equation and is everywhere differentiable. So without doing any math I can provide an answer.

Or at least, that *seems* to be the flaw. But $y(x) = 0$ is also the unique solution to the problem. To see this, consider a function $Y(x)$ that satisfies $Y''(x) = y(x)$. Do some FTC and integration by parts and you get
$$
x^2 Y'(x) -(x+1)Y(x) = Y'(1) - (1+x)Y(1).
$$
Differential equation solves to
$$
Y(x) = C\,xe^{-1/x} + Y(1) + (x-1)Y'(1),
$$
which can only be satisfied if $C = 0$. Thus, $y(x) = Y''(x) = 0$.

[Differentiating both sides twice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx*Integrate%5By%5Bt%5D,+%7Bt,+1,+x%7D%5D+-+(x+%2B+1)+Integrate%5B+t*y%5Bt%5D,+%7Bt,+1,+x%7D%5D,+%7Bx,+2%7D%5D) gives an equation that solves to $y(x) = Ce^{-1/x}/x^3$, but plugging that back into the original equation also gives $C = 0$.

So while the fact that this is the solution may be a flaw in the question, it *does* seem to be well-posed, in the sense that the solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

A commentary:

$$ \forall  x \in R-\{0\}~~~~~~~~(1)$$
$$x \int_{1}^{x} y(t) ~dt =(x+1)~\int_{1}^{x} t~y(t)~dt.~~~~~(2)$$
D.w.r.t. $x$
$$\int_{1}^{x} y(t) ~dt +xy=\int_{1}^{x} t~ y(t) ~dt + (x+1) xy.~~~~~~(3)$$ 
Eliminating second term on RHS by (1), we get
$$\int_{1}^{x} y(t)~dt= x^2(x+1) y(x). ~~~~~~(4)$$
From here it follows 
$$ y(1)=0 ~~~~~~~~(5)$$
Differentiate (4) w.r.t $x$, we get
$$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int \frac{1-3x^2-2x}{x^2+x^3}~dx +C.~~~~~(6)$$
We get $$ y(x) = \frac{C}{x^3}~ e^{-1/x}.~~~~~~~(7)$$
Resolution-1: In order to satisfy (5), $C=0$ so the solution is $y(x)=0$.
Usually (5) is either ignored or not obtained, hence the wrong solution (7) is admitted.
Let us now put (7) in (2), we get
$$ LHS= (1+x) e^{-1/x} -\frac{2x}{C}, ~RHS= (1+x) e^{-1/x} -\frac{x+1}{C}.$$
These two sides can be equal only for one isolated point $x=1$. This contradicts
the very first condition, namely, (1).

Resolution-2: This is an ill posed Integral equation which holds only for a isolated point $x=1$.
One can only differentiate only an identity or a relation ship which holds for a continuous domain of $x$ e.g., $[a,b].$

In short, a given Integral must actually hold in a continuous domain $[a,b]$,
otherwise the very first step of differentiation cannot be even initiated.